# how to judge a AndroidPackge is valid

Tags: android

I want to know if an android package is valid before i install it, but I have no idea how.
I want to try to get the package info, but the method i tried is not good. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you be more desciptive?

Comment: I download apk files in my app,I want to know if the apkfile could be installed

Comment: you mean you want to know this with the help of another application?

Comment: No,I want do this in my app.

Comment: It'd be nice if you outline what method was not 'good'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) and use [getApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)  which returns information about the package.

For example:

```
try {
    ApplicationInfo app = this.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.example.name", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the APK file on device you need [PackageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageArchiveInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). This returns package metadata or null if the package is invalid.